# Find the remainder when dividing by $37$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can i find the remainder of $13^{16}- 2^{25}\cdot 15^{16}$ when divided by $37$?

I have tried to verify if every factor is divisible by $37$ (which isn´t), but I can´t figure a way to find the solution.

Comment: Hint: $$13\equiv-24,6^2\equiv?\pmod{37}$$

Comment: $$10^3\equiv-1$$

Comment: *Easy* by repeated squaring, esp. since $\,15^{\large 2}\equiv \color{#c00}3,\ 13^{\large 4}\equiv -\color{#c00}3\equiv 2^{\large 8}\ $ so we can reuse results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that $2$ is a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) modulo $37$ - that is, all the first $36$ powers have a different remainder on division by $37$.

$$\small \begin{array}{c|c}
k & 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \\\hline
2^k \bmod 37 &
2 & 4 & 8 & 16 & -5 & -10 & 17 & -3 & -6 & -12 & 13 & -11 & 15 & -7 & -14 & 9 & 18 & -1
\end{array} $$

with the second  half being the negated versions of the same, with  $2^{36}\equiv 1\bmod 37$.

Then $13^{16} - 2^{25}\cdot 15^{16} \equiv (2^{11})^{16} - 2^{25}(2^{13})^{16} \equiv 2^{176}-2^{233}\equiv 2^{32} - 2^{17}\bmod 37$